# Is it possible to fire ng-click of a button element from a button in another controller?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to use `angular modal` for CRUD operation, so for firing the modal we have button by id `modalFire` in `ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl"` , this is my modal:

```
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">....</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="productForm" novalidate>
                <div>
                    <label for="ProductName"> productName :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="ProductName" id="ProductName" ng-model="model.ProductName" value="" required />

                </div>
                <div style="margin:10px">
                    <label for="Price">price :</label>
                    <input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" ng-model="model.Price" />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="Save()" ng-disabled="productForm.$invalid">save</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <button type="button" id="modalFire" class="btn btn-default modalBtn" ng-click="open()">UpdateProduct</button>
</div>
```

and it's controller:

```
 App.controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal) {


    $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
            size: size,
            resolve: {
                items: function () {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        });
    };
});

 App.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance,  $http) {      
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

and i have a grid that shows `ProductList` :

```
    <div ng-controller="ProductController" ng-init="GetAllProducts()">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:90px" ng-show="!ShowGrid">
        <article class="widget">
            <header class="widget__header">

                <div class="widget__title">
                    <i class="pe-7s-menu"></i><h3>ProductList</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="widget__config">
                    <a href="#"><i class="pe-7f-refresh"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="pe-7s-close"></i></a>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="widget__content table-responsive">

                <table class="table table-striped media-table">
                    <thead style="background-color:rgba(33, 25, 36,0.1)">
                        <tr>

                            <th style="width:30%">price</th>
                            <th style="width:30%">productName</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="product in Products">

                            <td>{{product.Price}}</td>
                            <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

so, i want a way to add a `button` or `<a> element` for each row in grid that can fire the modal, is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand your question, why not just add the button to your `ng-repeat` in your table. For example:

```
<table class="table table-striped media-table">
    <thead style="background-color:rgba(33, 25, 36,0.1)">
        <tr>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>ProductName</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="product in Products">
            <td>{{product.Price}}</td>
            <td>{{product.ProductName}}</td>
            <td><button ng-click="loadItem(product)>Edit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then inside your controller, just pass the product into your modal load function. For example:

```
$scope.loadItem = function(product){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        animation: true,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            product: function () {
                return product;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

See how you can pass the product to the function, and then use resolve to pass the product into the modal. In your modal controller you would attach the product to the `$scope`, and use it as you would any other view.

Comment: I want when i click on Edit, the modal comes up. i did as u said but the modal does not work!

Comment: Well create a fiddle showcasing your problem, otherwise we won't be able to help.